# How to find out where this ConcurrentModificationException crashes?

Tags: java, android

I am stuck with an `ConcurrentModificationException` and I Can't figure out where this happens in my code. All that Debug gives me is this:

```
myApp [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8631]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ConcurrentModificationException))   
        ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1631   
        ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1329 
        ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1944  
        ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 126 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3997    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 491  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 841  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 599 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Thread [<9> AsyncTask #1] (Running) 
    Thread [<10> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
    Daemon Thread [<12> RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@40770068] (Running)  
    Thread [<11> AsyncTask #3] (Running)
```

Comment: You should get a full stacktrace in your logcat. Either use `Window -> Show View -> Logcat` in eclipse or start the `ddms` app from your SDK folder. There should be a big red block with the tag *AndroidRuntime* after the crash.

Comment: The only thing Logcat shows isDEBUG/AndroidRuntime(899): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<  No bigred block...

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to note, in case you missed this: You have to resume execution when you are in debug mode and the debugger stops at the exception. The log statement gets printed when you see the "Force close" dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` occurs when you are modifying a collection while iterating over it. At this point it's probably easier to just search for a foreach loop where you are changing the collection.

Comment: I am doing of
map.getOverlays().add(...);
at different places. Would a lock/unlock help?

Comment: @michaelsmith: If it's inside a foreach locks won't help because you are not modifying it from different threads.

Comment: I actually do the modifs from different threads. So lock/unlock would be fine?

Comment: @michaelsmith: In that case yes. Make sure the locks are on the same object which is globally visible to all threads.